# No default constructor available for Base class error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, default-constructor, crtp

I am experimenting with *Policies* and *CRTP* and came across this issue.
So I am creating a `SmartPtr` which along with all customisation points also have releasing policy (the rest I will skip for the sake of simplicity)

```
template<typename T>
class Releaser
{
    int someDummyState;
public:
    Releaser(int st):someDummyState(st) {}
    void release()
    {
        cout << someDummyState << endl;
        static_cast<T*>(this)->data = nullptr;
    }
};

template<typename T, template<typename> typename Rel = Releaser>
class SmartPtr :
    public Rel<SmartPtr<T,Rel>>
{
public:
    SmartPtr(T* d,int val) :
        Rel(val), // This line is error prone, Rel<SmartPtr>(val) solves this
        data(d)
    {}

    T* operator*()
    {
        return data;
    }

private:
    friend class Releaser<SmartPtr>; // We need this as in the releaser we are accessing the private member
    T* data;
};

int main() 
{
    SmartPtr<int> S(new int(3),8); 
    S.release();
}
```

So this gives me `error C2512: 'Releaser<SmartPtr<int,Releaser>>': no appropriate default constructor available`

But I don't see how I am invoking a default constructor for the Rel? I believe I am explicitly passing the val to the constructor.
This issue is resolved the I specify the template parameter for Rel `(Rel<SmartPtr>(val))`.

Can someone please explain why I need to specify the base type template parameter and why it was trying to invoke the default constructor?

Comment: *Can someone please explain why I need to specify the base type template parameter and why it was trying to invoke the default constructor?* --Maybe because the syntax is exactly as if you are trying to default construct an object?  C++ has various places where you have to help the compiler out to disambiguate certain syntaxes, and this may be one of those situations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, How does   Rel(val),  this look like I am trying to default construct when I am passing an integer to the constructor?!

Comment: You're not getting my point:  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e2482fce0aaa932).  The compiler blindly assumes that `Rel` is a member variable, and you're trying to construct it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie still dont get your point. So the compiler doesnt understand that Rel is related to Rel<SmartPtr> and thinks its a member +  trying to call bases's constructor with no arguments.

Comment: `Rel<SmartPtr>` is the type.  That is not the same as plain-old `Rel`.  That's probably why the compiler is not equating the two.